# Apple Mach-O Linker Errors Xcode

Tags: iphone

I got this Error from Xcode when trying to run my app on my device.

```
Ld "/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Store_Locator_In_App-hbygxaouhvxmvwdudbwamekfbima/Build/Intermediates/Store Locator In App.build/Debug-iphoneos/Store Locator In App.build/Objects-normal/armv7s/Store Locator In App" normal armv7s
    cd "/Users/admin/Desktop/peboom 5"
    setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 5.1
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch armv7s -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.0.sdk -L/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Store_Locator_In_App-hbygxaouhvxmvwdudbwamekfbima/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos "-L/Users/admin/Desktop/peboom 5" -F/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Store_Locator_In_App-hbygxaouhvxmvwdudbwamekfbima/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -filelist "/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Store_Locator_In_App-hbygxaouhvxmvwdudbwamekfbima/Build/Intermediates/Store Locator In App.build/Debug-iphoneos/Store Locator In App.build/Objects-normal/armv7s/Store Locator In App.LinkFileList" -dead_strip -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -miphoneos-version-min=5.1 -lsqlite3.0 -framework MediaPlayer -framework AudioToolbox -framework AVFoundation -framework SystemConfiguration -framework CFNetwork -framework MobileCoreServices -framework MessageUI -framework CoreLocation -framework QuartzCore -framework MapKit -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -lGoogleAnalytics_NoThumb -lGoogleAnalytics -o "/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Store_Locator_In_App-hbygxaouhvxmvwdudbwamekfbima/Build/Intermediates/Store Locator In App.build/Debug-iphoneos/Store Locator In App.build/Objects-normal/armv7s/Store Locator In App"

ld: file is universal (3 slices) but does not contain a(n) armv7s slice: /Users/admin/Desktop/peboom 5/libGoogleAnalytics_NoThumb.a for architecture armv7s
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 1):

The new iPhone 5 processor has a custom ARMv7 core which uses a new architecture called **armv7s**.

The linker is returning that error because the armv7s slice is missing from the libGoogleAnalytics_NoThumb library you're referencing in your project.

Simply update the GoogleAnalitics SDK to the latest version (1.5.1) you can download here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/resources